# Mapping properties of complex cosine and sine.

Tags: complex-analysis

Conway in his [book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 46 explores the mapping properties of the exponential function $f(z)=e^z$.

Afterwards he asks in the exercises about the mapping properties of $\cos z$ and $\sin z$.

I'm starting with the cosine case. Using the formula $h(z)=\cos z=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$, we have this function maps the lines $x=a$ and $y=c$ to the arithmetic mean of two symmetric rays with angles $a$ and $-a$ and the arithmetic mean of two circles centered in the origin of radius $e^c$ and $\frac{1}{e^c}$ respectively. Am I in the right way? am I missing some information? can I use the same method with the sine function?

Comment: What is the arithmetic mean of two lines?

Comment: @Justpassingby geometrically speaking? I don't know.

Comment: In this case you are taking the geometric mean of a point on one of the lines with a point on the other line, but the two points are not at equal distances from the intersection so you could still get a fairly general-looking curve.

Comment: Hint: the cosine is periodic, even in the complex plane.